# Declared enum and IF on its elements

Tags: c++, if-statement, enums, comparison

I'm working on Snake game. Although I have a little problem. I created enum with possible directions:

```
    enum Direction{
    n = 0, // north
    e = 1, // east
    s = 2, // south
    w = 3 // west
};
```

And then I created a ChangeDirection() function, which basing on previous direction will change it. (For example, if you go to the right/east, you can't switch to left/west):

```
void ChangeDirection(char key){
    switch (key){
    case 'w':
        if (Direction != 2)
            Direction = 0;
        break;
    case 'd':
        if (Direction != 3)
            Direction = 1;
        break;
    case 's':
        if (Direction != 0)
            Direction = 2;
        break;
    case 'a':
        if (Direction != 1)
            Direction = 3;
        break;
    }
```

But my ifs clearly don't work; following error occurs:

> Expected primary-expression before '!=' token

Anyone could help? How can I rearrange it to work? Why doesn't it work? Thanks!

Comment: Where is your `Direction` instance?

Comment: `Direction` is a *type name* not a variable. You need a *variable* of the type `Direction`.

Comment: I've created variable `Direction dir;`
then plugged **dir** into **ifs**, but still doesn't work. Seems like I don't know how to use enums, but I feel like I need them here :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Direction CurrentDir = e; // somewhere in the code

// ....

//another place in the code, so on..

CurrentDir = s; 

//....



void ChangeDirection(char key){
    switch (key){
    case 'w':
        if (CurrentDir != s)
            CurrentDir = n;
        break;
    case 'd':
        if (CurrentDir != w)
            CurrentDir = e;
        break;
   // so on ..
    }
```